# HTML5 Canvas fillRect bleeding

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here's some code where I:

1. Fill a bunch of points with red: (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)
2. Observe the color of a point I did not fill with red: (2, 4)

One would expect that that point would be `{ red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0 }`, as it is with any other pixel on the Canvas.

In fact, it is `{ alpha: 1, blue: 0, green: 0, red: 255 }`.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.fillStyle = "#f00";

// Fill a bunch of points

context.fillRect(1, 1, 1, 1);
context.fillRect(2, 1, 1, 1);
context.fillRect(2, 2, 1, 1);
context.fillRect(2, 3, 1, 1);

// Retrieve color at (2, 4), which I did not fill in

var point = { x: 2, y: 4 }

var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var start = (point.x + canvas.width * point.y) * 4;
var subarray = imageData.data.subarray(start, start + 4);

// Observe results

console.log({
  red:   subarray[0],
  green: subarray[1],
  blue:  subarray[2],
  alpha: subarray[3],
});
```

A JSFiddle is here, if you want to reproduce it at home: https://jsfiddle.net/vp0f3ahb/

*Note:* This JSFiddle really does reproduce the example. All I do on my computer is press the play button and observe the console. I'm hearing that it doesn't reproduce on some people's computers. This makes me wonder if this is a browser bug?

**My question is this:** How is this possible? How did `fillRect` manage to bleed over into other pixels, even when I'm clearly setting the width and height of the pixel to be drawn to be (1, 1)?

P.S. I've found that a way to fix this is to call clearRect() on the entire Canvas before doing any drawing. I don't really care about that; I just want to know what on earth is going on here.

Comment: In my browser it's showing results as expected. I have changed color from red(#f00) to green(#0f0) and it's showing result {red: 0, green: 255, blue: 0, alpha: 255} only iff point(2,4) is filled with it. Else it will show result {red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0} if it's untouched https://jsfiddle.net/vp0f3ahb/5/

Comment: As Shoaib, I'm unable to reproduce and seem to work as expected. https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/vp0f3ahb/6/ (Firefox, Opera). Normally a "bleed" would be caused by the point being drawn on top of the coordinate system and would require one to translate the context 0.5 pixel x/y, but this is not needed in this example. Is this the full code, or does the actual code (if it isn't) use transforms? - OR - in what browser do you get the problem?

Comment: @K3N , Shoaib Konnur, I can reproduce this on both Chrome 55.0 and Firefox 50.0 on macOS Sierra.

Comment: And yes, the JSFiddle is the entire reproducible example. I simply press the run button on the fiddle and observe the results in the console.

Comment: Here is what I get [image snapshot](https://i.imgur.com/NKkKDW5.png) also Firefox 50.1.0, but on Windows. Seem to be related to the graphic sub-system of the OS. What result does [this version](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/vp0f3ahb/7/) give you?

Comment: @K3N Your version gives me `{red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 128}`.

Comment: One final: Are you running on retina display? Could you check the pixel aspect ratio you have in the browser? (window.devicePixelRatio)

Comment: @K3N Nope, I'm not on a retina display. I don't know how to check my pixel aspect ratio, and google gives no help.

Comment: Oh I see :P My ratio is 1.

Comment: It could be a bug with the graphic sub-system. The browsers tend to use the underlying system to handle graphics which could explain why it affect both browsers. You would probably get the same result with Safari. The values doesn't make much sense. An alpha such as 64, 128 would make more sense but a value of 1 seem to indicate a rounding error, but then there is a full value for red channel which points to a possible bug in how the composition/alpha-blending is done... sorry, I am out of guesses - I would search for Mac specific issues related to this... :-/

Comment: @K3N To me, it's very reminiscent of how strokeRect works, which is that if you stroked mostly on one pixel and just barely on another, the second pixel would get the same color, but with just a tiny bit of alpha. So my guess is it is a rounding error, somewhere. Meh. I'll wait the 2 days and toss a bounty on it to see if anyone knows...

Comment: @K3N and OP, I'm also on osX (but mavericks), non-retina and I can't reproduce the original one (on any browser), however I also have the same result as OP for the translated one (alpha 128)

Comment: @Kaiido & OP: what graphics cards do you use? Could OP try to toggle hardware acceleration in the browser to off to see if it affects the rendering. If you use same card, what version of the drivers do you have? If not the same, OP, check if there is a newer version of the display driver.

Comment: @thedayturns the strokeRect behavior is more related to sub-pixeling with fractional positions and sizes. The numbers you get indicate a different problem (why I was boggled with the numbers for the alpha).

Comment: @K3N, I'm using an internal Intel HD Graphics 3000, in an early 2011 13" macbook-pro and my .kext's (osX kind of driver) version is 8.24.17. But I'll try from my Sierra disk partition in the week-end to see if it comes from the OS.